# Firebase i can login but i cant register

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make an authentication application. I connected to firebase and turned on e-mail and password authentication, I can add a user in firebase and log in with that user, but I get an error when registering for a user who is not in firebase.

```
W/System  (27047): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: It is not an error. It is a warning as it mentioned as 'W'. Sharing your code and logs properly make any help more possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<void> createUserWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    try {
      await Auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _controllerEmail.text, password: _controllerPassword.text);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = e.message;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Future<void> createUserWithEmailAndPassword() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _controllerEmail.text, password: _controllerPassword.text);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    setState(() {
      errorMessage = e.message;
    });
  }
}
```

obs: Check if the controllers are not passing empty values

Comment: i did and and i can take value